# Compiler shows the error message "makes pointer from integer without cast" (reversing an array). How do i resolve this?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

The code goes as follows. while calling the function reverse_array, How do I define the first function argument as an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* a, int* b);
void reverse_array(int a[], int n) {
  int* b = a + n - 1;
  while (b > a) {
    swap(a, b);
    a = a + 1;
    b = b - 1;
  }
}

void swap(int* ptra, int* ptrb) {
  int t;
  t = *ptra;
  *ptra = *ptrb;
  *ptrb = t;
}

main() {
  int b[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  reverse_array(b[5], 5);
  int x;
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    printf("%d", b[x]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. `reverse_array(b[5], 5);` should be `reverse_array(b, 5);`

Comment: `b[5]` is an `int` and it's out of bounds. The name of the array is not `b[5]` but `b`.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I often see this type of error, so this shouldn't be typo but an error came from misunderstanding. Better action should be searching for a question to use in duplicate vote.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica yes, it's really not a typo here. From a beginner's perspective `b[5]` could look somewhat like the name of the array.

Comment: How is this post off-topic? Duplicate maybe but certainly not off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

`b[5]` is not the entire array but 6th element (the index start from 0) of the array, which doesn't exists.

You should pass `b` instead. This will be converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

> *Compiler shows the error message “makes pointer from integer without cast” (reversing an array). How do i resolve this?*

Do not pass an `int` to where a pointer is expected. :)

Background:

In the context of a function definition something like `int a[]` is the same as `int * a`, so `a` is a pointer to `int`.

You caller passes `b[5]`, which is the 6th element of the `int`-array `b`, so it's an `int` (and BTW an out-of-bound access, as in C array are `0`-based so `b`'s element are addressed via indexes ranging from 0 to 4.

To "pass" the array just give `b`.

```
  reverse_array(b, 5);
```

The array `b` would then be decayed to the address of its 1st element. This address is received within the function as value `a`.

Answer (score 1):

> When you write

```
`reverse_array(b[5], 5)`,
```

> you are passing an int to the function as first parameter not an
>   array of int.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? While it is poorly formatted and a bit terse, it still is a valid answer. Perhaps we should not demotivate new users so deliberately